# dart cli apps and gc

Tags: dart, garbage-collection, command-line-interface

I've built a cli app in dart which looks to be taking a large amount of ram (175MB).

The cli app is doing a full scan of my filesystem.

The ram is allocated within the first few seconds of the cli app starting so I don't believe the scan is responsible for the memory allocation.
I've also had the app running for multiple days (re-scanning every few minutes) and memory usage is not growing.
It feels more like dart is aggressively allocating heap on startup.

I've googled but found very little information on how dart manages memory and gc for a cli/server side dart app.

With flutter it appears that flutter triggers a gc whenever it has spare time at the end of drawing a frame but of course there is no equivalent in a cli app.

I believe the data sdk does exposes an api for triggering a gc but it's my understanding that this is only available in debug mode.

So I guess there are several questions here.

1. what is dart's memory allocation strategy on startup for a cli app?
   Does it have a default amount of memory that it allocates?
   If so how does it determine the default (does it depend on the amount of system ram?)
2. is there some way to control how much ram dart pre-allocates (like the java -Xms commands)
3. does a cli app need to do anything special to ensure that gc is run?
4. my app is a heavy user of waitFor - does this interfere with gc.

For reference the app in questions:
https://github.com/noojee/batman

Answer (score 1):

My observations so far.

Tests conducted with Dart 2.14 on Ubuntu 21.10

## 1) memory allocated on startup.

Summary: jit mode 370MB, compiled < 30MB

I've been profiling a small cli app that scans the entire hard drive so the following is from observations. (code below).

You get quite different results depending on how you start the app.

### JIT mode

If you run `dart scan.dart`

On startup the app Reserves 370 MB but on
My small app looked to have allocated 20-30MB of that.
My app appear to use 20-30MB for the entire run but the 370MB remained reserved.

### compiled

After compiling the script via: `dart compile exe scan.dart`
I then ran the script again

On startup the app consumed just under 30MB.

## 2) can you control pre-allocation

If not found any method of doing this and the dart cli tool help gives no hint that it exists.

## 3) Does a cli app need to worry about gc

You don't need to do anything special for gc to work in a  dart cli app.

## 4) Does waitFor affect gc?

waitFor appears to have no affect on gc.

Test code

```dart
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:dcli/dcli.dart';

void main() {
  var count = 0;
  find(
    '*',
    workingDirectory: '/',
    types: <FileSystemEntityType>[Find.directory, Find.file],
    includeHidden: true,
  ).forEach((file) {
    count++;
    if (count % 1000 == 0) {
      print(count);
    }
  });
}
```

pubspec.yaml

```yaml
name: scan
version: 1.0.0
homepage: https://dcli.noojee.dev
documentation: https://dcli.noojee.dev
description: scan drive and say hello
repository: https://github.com/noojee/dcli
environment: 
  sdk: '>=2.14.0 <3.0.0'
dependencies: 
  dcli: ^1.14.2
  dcli_core: ^0.0.4
```